# Temporary connection between two individual very small wires

Tags: connector

I've separated a bunch of phone wire to connect a bunch of small devices (small motors, switches, buttons, electromagnets, etc all embedded in Lego blocks) and I need a way to temporarily connect them. I have some connectors like this:

[image]

But they're far too big and bulky, I need something tiny, it doesn't have to fit very tightly or be insulated, it would be nice if there was only one kind (so any two could connect together). Maybe some kind of micro alligator clip? Magnetic connections? Maybe little jewellery clasps? Or like this?

[image]

Surely instead of making my own I can go buy a bag of something, right? How do most hobbyists handle this?

Comment: If you immerse the ends of the wire into a molten alloy of some kind (heated by a small handheld device), and with suitable flux, you can join them temporarily quite readily. A bit of heatshrink tubing or tape will supply insulation where required.

Comment: What about jumper wires https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/141

Comment: What about hand twisting, since you do not need insulation?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany either doesn't understand what "temporary" might mean in the context of alligator clips and magnets, or didn't catch that "embedded in Lego blocks" might mean that the solution might need to at least somewhat child safe and quick and easy to use and reuse in a modular fashion.

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy Those look a bit bulky and what would I plug them into?

Comment: @Triak That's what I'm doing now and the tiny wires are starting to break and stuff. It needs to be highly reusable because that's how Lego rolls.

Comment: Child-safe was not in the requirements, and crimping connections is probably not child-friendly either. Soldering wires to motors etc. would allow use of a solderless breadboard, which is what most hobbyists use for temporary connections.

Comment: BTW, the term for the kind of connector you're proposing is "hermaphroditic".

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I would do the crimping, the user would just plug them into each other. The smallest breadboards I can find would make the project about 3x as large. Something like that, but just large enough to accommodate a single connection is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Bullet connectors used by RC guys are not hermaphrodite, but they otherwise might work for you. 3mm diameter is a common smaller size. Look for gold bullet connector. You'd have to solder them on the ends of the wires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small solderless breadboard (photo from Adafruit) used by electronics hobbyists:

[image]

Only 1.4 x 1.6".

Bullet connectors (photo from robotshop.com) used by RC hobbists.

[image]

Comment: Selected for the bullet connectors, not the breadboard.

Answer (score 5):

You can get screwdriverless terminal blocks like these: -

[image]

Solder two together and it makes a 4-way wire connector. Here's one that looks useful: -

[image]

And you can multi-way versions like these: -

[image]

These look useful too: -

[image]

[link](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1074)

Comment: Are the white bits on top levers that release the wire?

Comment: @gunfulker try searching on "cam-lever connector" or terminal block

Answer (score 4):

For *really temporary* connections, jumper wires with grabber clips, like these, are very commonly used. They can grab onto a lot of different things, including each other.

[image: grabber clips]
<sub>(source: [apogeekits.com](http://www.apogeekits.com/images/smd_clip_test_leads.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Very nice but far too big.

Answer (score 2):

The phone company uses punch down blocks...

[image]

...to connect pairs of phone wire. This method is super fast because you do not need to strip or crimp the wire before punching it down.

Some blocks have metal clips that bridge the connections. These can make debugging problems very quick since you can make and break connections without ever disconnecting the actual wires....

[image]

Punch down blocks as create a nicely organized layout rather than a big mess of wires.

The blocks come in [many sizes and shapes](http://www.amazon.com/s/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&field-keywords=punch%20down%20block)....

[image]

[image]

Some punch down blocks even have places to label the incoming and outgoing connections...

[image]

...which also helps keep things organized.

You will need a [punch down tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0072K1QHM), available for $10-$20 from amazon.
[image]

Once you get the block and the tool, you will be able to make lots secure connections in less than 1 second.

Comment: How do you remove the wires? I know you can stick a flat-blade screwdriver in there and twist it to spread the tangs, but is there a more controlled method?

Comment: Something like this but for individual connections with maybe some kind of release mechanism would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

From professional to ghetto

1. Mini alligator clips or test clips.  With or without leads on them. Lead less clips, just use the clips to hold the two wires in the jaws together.
2. Small paper clips. Same as lead less clips above.
3. Aluminum foil folded over into small strips. Roll or fold over wire joint, then crimp with some pliers.
4. Twist the wires together. Duh.

Mini clips are quite small and handy. 
http://www.tubelab.com/images/MeterUse/B-Clips.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 24 AWG solid wire such as telephone wire (from a 25-pair or larger telephone cable) *or* wire from a cat-5 cable for your temporary jumpers, there is an easy and reliable solution for making temporary connections.

You need to get a machine-pin IC socket.  You can then break the pins free from the plastic socket and solder the tail end of the pin to whatever wire you want to connect to.  Then cover with small heat-shrink tubing, making sure to leave the opening in the socket pin open.

Now you can just use 24 AWG solid wire to connect to whatever you want to connect to.  24 AWG wire is a perfect fit into those socket pins and this makes a *very* reliable connection.

---

[EDIT]

I just noticed that you would like connectors that are the same for both ends of the connection.

A company called EDAC makes rectangular connectors that are popular in the professional audio industry.  Their pins are small and flat and have a slit up the middle.  Two such connectors mate by sliding the slits on top of each other.  In other words, the flat part of one pin is rotated 90 degrees with respect to the other so that the slits mate up.  They then just push together.

Here is an example of the connector pins: [EDAC pin](http://media.digikey.com/Photos/EDAC%20Photos/516-290-500_sml.jpg)  They are available as solder-tab, crimp, PCB mount.

These pins are highly reliable because of the wiping action that occurs as they mate.

Doing a Google search on "edac pins" brings up multiple suppliers.  They are also readily available from places like eBay.

Digikey has them as part # 151-1049-ND costing about $0.50 each in hundreds.  eBay cost is about half of that (200 pcs $50)